# mysql rows 16-21

Tags: mysql

If I have a table:  `ID, num,varchar`

where `ID` is an integer, either 1,2 or 3.
then `num` is a number, counting from 1 to 100.
`varchar` is just some text.

So in total we have 300 rows, in no particular ordering in this table.

What query can I use to get the rows with `ID`=2 and `num` from 16-21 out of this table?

(resulting in 6 rows total)

Comment: 16 to 21, it should return 6 rows ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT * from yourtable where ID = 2 AND num >= 16 AND num <= 21
```

Or, equivalent using [BETWEEN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)

```
SELECT * from yourtable where ID = 2 AND num BETWEEN 16 AND 21
```

Create an index to have faster lookups later (but will slow down your inserts a bit):

```
CREATE INDEX indexname on yourtable (ID,num);
```

Comment: Which of these would be faster?

Comment: These are equally fast. If you need performance, add indexes on ID and num. See updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID = 2 AND NUM > 15 AND NUM < 22;
```

where `TABLE` is the name of your table. In general, given that you're selecting on columns ID and NUM they should probably be indexed for faster retrieval (ie the database doesn;t have to check every row). Although given your table is small it probably wont make much difference here.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 2 AND num > 15 AND num < 22
```